# ORA-01847 day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Tags: php, android, sql, oracle

i made some research about it but i couldn't figure it out. My problem is i can't add new record oracle database because of ORA-01847 error.

I try to add this date value to database: 23.07.2017 18:10:00

```
$MYDATE= $data[$i]->MYDATE;
//I ALSO ADD THIS LINE
$str = oci_parse($conn, "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'");
oci_execute($str);
//
$sql = 'INSERT INTO MYTABLE(ID,MYDATE)'.'VALUES(:ID,:MYDATE)';
$compiled = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':ID', $ID);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':MYDATE', $MYDATE);
oci_execute($compiled);
```

however it gave me error:

> ORA-01847 day of month must be between 1 and last day of month error.

Comment: Show us what the string $MYDATE contains

Comment: What is datatype of `MYTABLE.MYDATE`???

Comment: datatype is DATE

Comment: Did you try `$sql = "INSERT INTO MYTABLE(ID,MYDATE) VALUES (:ID,TO_DATE(:MYDATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))";`?

Answer (score 0):

You can additionally try to execute this line after you change `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` in your php code.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'AMERICAN';
```

It is possible sometimes  that setting `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` has no effect if `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` is unset.

Comment: Now it gave ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE error

Comment: is your id column of number datatype?

Answer (score -3):

add this trigger your database

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER USER_NAME.MY_SET_DATE after logon on database
begin
if (user = 'USER_NAME') then
execute immediate
'alter session set nls_date_format = ''YYYY-MM-DD'' ';
-- execute immediate
--'ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE' ;

end if;
end my_set_date;
```